# One CPU core at 100% load

Tags: 14.04, cpu-load

I recently rebooted my PC after a system update and noticed that I have at least one CPU core at 100% load.

I tried rebooting but the problem remains.

[image: One core at 100% load]

The result of the top is shown below :
[image: top command results]

Comment: Using a core for less than 100% is a waste of resources. You paid for that core why not use it to its fullest? And the generic piece of software to go to is `top` (and `htop`). Please add the results of `top` to the question. It will list the processes with the heaviest at the top.

Comment: Please add the output of `htop` too, to your question.

Comment: The result of the "top" command shows a process "apport" depending on root to be using CPU between 95 and 100 %. Hope this will help you

Comment: The ubuntu system is obviously idle when performing the test

Comment: after a system update (uname -a 
Linux PC-DE-LDP 4.4.0-36-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 12 11:49:30 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) the problem remains. "apport" process taking 86 to 100% cpu

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to disable apport to run .

The "apport" process description and usage is [apport there](https://goo.gl/8jVGK)

I used [How do I enable or disable Apport?](http://goo.gl/HjGyb) to disable it.

The MOST important drawback of this method is that the "apport" process won't be able to detect problems and to report them.

Is this drawback not too important compared to seeing the process taking all CPU on one core ?

The document describing the apport process seems to tell that it's only useful on unstable version and normally set do disabled.